# Inserir dados do webservice no sqlite

Tags: java, android

Tenho um webservice que me retorna os seguintes dados

CodigoDisciplina, Disciplina, CodigoTurma.

Partindo de um principio que o professor pode ter mais de uma disciplina, por exemplo,

CodigoDisciplina: 22, Disciplina: Portugues, CodigoTurma:40

CodigoDisciplina: 23, Disciplina: Matematica, CodigoTurma:40

Tenho uma tabela no SQLite os mesmos atributos acima, preciso receber esses dados e inserir no banco de dados. Abaixo segue o código que implementei, porem o problema é que está inserindo somente o ultimo registro, no caso por exmplo:

CodigoDisciplina: 23, Disciplina: Matematica, CodigoTurma:40

**Classe do WebService**

```
public class WsDisciplinas {
private static String SOAP_ACTION ="http://feol/DisciplinasProfessor";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://feol/";
private static String METHOD_NAME= "DisciplinasProfessor";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.43.175/ServiceFeol.asmx?WSDL";

ArrayList<Disciplinas> listDisciplinas = new ArrayList<>();
Disciplinas disciplinas = new Disciplinas();

public ArrayList<Disciplinas> disciplinas(String codProfessor){

    try {
        SoapObject resposta = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            resposta.addProperty("CodigoPro", codProfessor);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(resposta);

        HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        http.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        String resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resultado);

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++ ) {

            JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            disciplinas.setCodDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("CodMat"));
            disciplinas.setDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("Materia"));
            disciplinas.setCodTurma(jsonObject.getString("CodTur"));


            listDisciplinas.add(i,disciplinas);
        }
    }  catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
        soapFault.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return listDisciplinas;
}
```

}

**Classe DAO persiste os dados**

```
public class DaoDisciplinas {

private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private BancoDados bancoDados;

public DaoDisciplinas(Context context) {bancoDados = new BancoDados(context);}
public String insereDisciplinas(ArrayList<Disciplinas> disciplinasList) {

    ContentValues valores;
    long resultado = 1;

    for (int i =0; i<disciplinasList.size();i++){
        dataBase = bancoDados.getWritableDatabase();
        valores = new ContentValues();

        valores.put("CODDISCIPLINA", disciplinasList.get(i).getCodTurma());
        valores.put("DISCIPLINA", disciplinasList.get(i).getDisciplina());
        valores.put("CODTURMA", disciplinasList.get(i).getCodTurma());


        resultado = dataBase.insertOrThrow("DISCIPLINA", null, valores);
        dataBase.close();

        valores.put("CODDISCIPLINA", disciplinasList.get(i).getCodTurma());
        valores.put("DISCIPLINA", disciplinasList.get(i).getDisciplina());
        valores.put("CODTURMA", disciplinasList.get(i).getCodTurma());

        dataBase.close();

    }
    if (resultado == -1)
        return "Erro de registro";
    else
        return "Registro Inserido com sucesso";

}
```

}

**Classe da activity que executa a ação de baixar do webservice e chamar a classe dao passando o ArrayList retornado pelo webService.**

```
public class DisciplinaActivity extends Activity {


DaoDisciplinas daoDisciplinas = new DaoDisciplinas(this);
WsDisciplinas wsDisciplinas = new WsDisciplinas();
private Button btSincronizar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_disciplina);
```

btSincronizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSincronizar);
        btSincronizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btSincronizarOnClick();

```
        }

    });


}

private void btSincronizarOnClick() {


    String msg = getString(R.string.dlg_msg);
    String titulo = getString(R.string.dlg_titulo);

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, titulo, msg);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                ArrayList<Disciplinas> disciplinasList = wsDisciplinas.disciplinas("101");
                daoDisciplinas.insereDisciplinas(disciplinasList);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserido com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            t.show(); ///gravar na tabela
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }).start();


}
```

}

Comment: Depure e veja a quantidade que tem dentro de "disciplinasList.size()" no teu DAO, e no momento que você adiciona, podes fazer apenas "disciplinasList.add(disciplina)", em vez de definir uma posição passando o "i".

Comment: Cara sou iniciante em android, como faço depurar?

Comment: Na IDE que você utiliza, (Android Studio ou Eclipse), posicione sobre a linha e aperte Ctrl+F8, ele vai marcar a linha para depuração. E no menu "Run", escolha "Debug app". Ele vai executar e parar nessa linha.

Comment: Amigo com a depuração achei o seguinte, meu JSONObject, esta correto ele esta com as 2 disciplinas diferentes, ou seja, o webservice está retornando corretamente. O problema e no list de disciplinas ele esta sendo preenchido 2 vezes com a ultima disciplna do JSONObject. Depurei a linha do return

Answer (score 1):

O problema aqui é o seguinte: Você está alocando o MESMO objeto na lista. Olha só:

```
Disciplinas disciplinas = new Disciplinas();
...
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++ ) {
   ...
   disciplinas.setCodDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("CodMat"));
   disciplinas.setDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("Materia"));
   disciplinas.setCodTurma(jsonObject.getString("CodTur"));
   listDisciplinas.add(i,disciplinas);
}
```

Você criou uma variável disciplina e alocou memória para armazenar seus dados utilizando o comando new. Quando isso acontece, mudar os dados desse objeto apenas muda os dados armazenados nesse endereço de memória. Significa que tudo que estiver apontando pra esse endereço de memória será afetado. Nesse caso, o listDisciplinas tem n referências a essa variável, mas todas elas apontando pro mesmo endereço de memória. Por isso só é inserido o último item adicionado, porque cada set na variável disciplinas sobrescreve o valor para todas as referências a posição de memória dessa variável, i.e., listDisciplinas vai conter 'n' itens com os dados da última disciplina. Para você conseguir criar diferentes objetos disciplinas e alterá-los independentemente, é só mover a declaração da variável disciplinas para dentro do for:

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++ ) {
   Disciplinas disciplinas = new Disciplinas();
   disciplinas.setCodDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("CodMat"));
   disciplinas.setDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("Materia"));
   disciplinas.setCodTurma(jsonObject.getString("CodTur"));
   listDisciplinas.add(i,disciplinas);
}
```

A cada iteração do for você constrói um objeto diferente. Assim, a adição de um objeto na lista poderá ser feita sem afetar os outros objetos da mesma. Espero ter ajudado ^^

Comment: Excelente explicação.